# Are there any good NSIS alternatives specifically for Java projects?

Tags: java, scripting, ant, installation, nsis

Are there any good scriptable installer/uninstaller systems made for Java projects? Ideally a system that interfaces well with Ant build scripts.

Comment: Have you had a look at the many questions about this?  Try searching for "java installer" - the search box is at the upper right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used [AntInstaller](http://antinstaller.sourceforge.net/) in the past and was pretty happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not Java-specific, our product [InstallBuilder](http://installbuilder.bitrock.com) is often used to package Java applications and has built-in actions for autodetecting Java, etc.

It can be run from the command line and integrates will with Ant. Unlike NSIS, it is commercial, though we have discounts for small ISVs

Comment: Looks nice, but I was looking for something free.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but I suggest looking at  [NDJS](http://ndjs.io) - a new free and open source framework for installers.

I should mention I'm the creator of it, but check it out ...